# Remove index duplicates, data in one row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates, row

In my dataframe there are duplicates in the index. How can I remove those duplicates in the index and have the data just in one row? So the start can be seen in screenshot 1, the aim in 2.

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPIZG.png)
[Aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0ctb.png)

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, data or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, you can use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on `level=0`:

```
out = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

           A     B
weight  0,05  0,04
size    0,02  0,01
```